# Как настроить связь между данными с разных листов в гугл таблицах и сделать вычисления

Tags: google-spreadsheet, таблицы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли создать такую функцию в гугл таблицах, чтобы при заполнении определенных столбцов листа в одном столбце появляилсь (вычислялись) значения, которые соответствуют таблице значений со второго листа гугл таблицы?
Чтобы понятнее было, о чем я - пример: измерение влажности воздуха при помощи гигрометра ВИТ. По известной разнице показаний прибора и температуре сухого градусника в таблице гигрометра ищется искомое значение влажности. Можно ли реализовать вычисление влажности следующим образом: на 1 листе гугл таблиц сами показания гигрометра, на втором листе есть таблица гигрометра. Зная данные со второго листа (таблица с гигрометра), настроить вычисление искомой влажности на 1 листе?

Comment: `vlookup` какой нить.

Comment: поделитесь тестовой таблицей с данными, чтобы можно было помочь вам

Comment: исправьте заголовок на вашу конкретную проблему, а не название целого раздела в учебнике

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1btS4Q5sxre-2ghunn-lCkWxHpemDzkZ7zwmSOpcmpvQ/edit?usp=sharing
Вот пример таблицы

Comment: @Pascal16 если вопрос еще актуален, то попробуйте конкретнее объяснить что и где должно отображаться. Если я правильно понял, что на первом листе в ячейке `G65` должно отобразиться значение `46` со второго листа?

Comment: @ZxNuClear да, всё верно! Вопрос еще актуален.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разместите в своей таблице в ячейке `G65` следующую формулу:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ВПР(E65; 'Таблица'!$A$2:$W$22; ПОИСКПОЗ(F65; 'Таблица'!$A$1:$W$1; 0); 0))
```

далее можете просто протягивать ее на необходимое количество ячеек вниз